# ckanext-security error while installing dependencies

Tags: ckan

Tried to load the ckanext-security into ckan2.10 and used Dockerfile to install the .whl files for the following

- pyotp==2.6.0
- python-magic==0.4.24
- redis==3.5.3
- WebOb==1.8.7
- repoze.who==2.4
- six==1.16.0

In the requirement.txt, it also stated to install the "beaker-py". I have tried to install "beaker-py" and its dependencies, but encountered error when I install the dependencies, error message: ERROR: pydantic_core-2.16.2-cpp311-cp311-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

May I know how can I overcome this issue?